# MySQL Order By in Right Join Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I'm trying to do a right join in MySQL like so:

```
SELECT customers.id,customers.firstname,customers.lastname,customers.email,orders.time,orders.notes,pendings.date_updated,pendings.issue,appointments.closed,appointments.job_description,backup_plans.expiration FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN orders
ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
ORDER BY orders.time DESC LIMIT 1
RIGHT JOIN pendings
ON customers.id = pendings.customer_id
ORDER BY pendings.date_updated DESC LIMIT 1
RIGHT JOIN appointments
ON customers.id = appointments.customer_id
ORDER BY appointments.closed DESC LIMIT 1
RIGHT JOIN backup_plans
ON customers.id = backup_plans.customer_id
ORDER BY backup_plans.expiration DESC LIMIT 1
```

My intent is this: to select customers' name and email, along with the most recent order, pending, appointment, and backup plan exploration. When I execute this I get a syntax error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RIGHT JOIN pendings
ON customers.id = pendings.customer_id
ORDER BY pendings.d' at line 5
```

I'm unfamiliar with joins and would appreciate any help.

---

**EDIT 1:**

It seems that I need to make a subquery per DanK's suggestion like so:

```
SELECT customers.id,customers.firstname,customers.lastname,customers.email,orderstmp.time,orderstmp.notes FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT orders.time,orders.notes,orders.customer_id FROM orders ORDER BY orders.time DESC LIMIT 1
) as orderstmp ON orderstmp.customer_id = customers.id
```

But when I do this, I only get one row result, whereas I want **all** the customer information.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Per Tom H's suggestion, I've built this query:

```
SELECT
    customers.id,
    SQ_O.time,
    SQ_O.notes
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        customers.id,
        orders.time,
        orders.notes
    FROM customers
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
    ORDER BY orders.time DESC LIMIT 1
) AS SQ_O ON SQ_O.id = customers.id
```

which has all blank time and notes fields

and

```
SELECT
    customers.id,
    O1.time,
    O1.notes
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders AS O1 ON O1.customer_id = O1.id
LEFT JOIN orders AS O2 ON O2.customer_id = customers.id AND O2.time > O1.time WHERE O2.customer_id IS NULL
```

Which reaches max execution time. I'm guessing this is due to my lack of familiarity with what's possible in MySQL in comparison to other dialects.

I also tried **Correlated subqueries** like this:

```
SELECT
    customers.firstname,
    customers.lastname,
    customers.email,
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(orders.time,': ',orders.notes)
        FROM orders
        WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id
        ORDER BY orders.time DESC LIMIT 1
    ) as last_order
FROM customers
```

But the "last_order" column comes up blank.

---

**FINAL, DISAPPOINTING EDIT**

After trying a number of really stellar suggestions that helped me learn SQL significantly, I decided to write a PHP script to get me what I want. The project's under a bit of a deadline so whatever works, works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can only have one ORDER BY statement per query.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RIGHT JOIN pendings
ON customers.id = pendings.customer_id
ORDER BY pendings.d' at line 5

Comment: Everyone else has pretty much covered the core problem; but I am left wondering. Why a `RIGHT` join? Are you expecting there to be `orders`, `pendings`, `appointments`, or `backup_plans` records without customers records associated?

Comment: @Uueerdo Because I'm a n00b. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For your latest edit, you need a comma after `email` and before `(SELECT`; and the subquery shouldn't JOIN to customers, it should have  a `WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.id` (referencing the outer query is what makes it "correlated".

Comment: @Uueerdo I changed it as I understand you and put the results above.

Comment: That looks right as far as I can tell (I usually avoid correlated queries if possible, and it almost always is). Are you sure there are orders with customer_id values matching customers.id values?

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one `ORDER BY` statement per query. You can of course use subqueries and refer to a result set as a virtual table but ultimately in a single `SELECT` you can only have one `ORDER BY`.

For instance:

```
SELECT something
FROM table
ORDER BY something -- One order By
```

With a subquery as a virtual table:

```
SELECT something
FROM (SELECT anotherthing, something
      FROM table
      ORDER BY anotherthing) -- this is an order by in a separate select statement..
ORDER BY something -- still only one Order by
```

------**EDIT**--------

For assistance with your join syntax, try something like this:

```
SELECT --fields,    
FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
RIGHT JOIN pendings ON customers.id = pendings.customer_id
RIGHT JOIN appointments ON customers.id = appointments.customer_id
RIGHT JOIN backup_plans ON customers.id = backup_plans.customer_id
ORDER BY orders.time DESC, pendings.date_updated DESC, appointments.closed DESC, backup_plans.expiration DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Close, but what I need it to do is select **every** customer, and `LIMIT` the orders, pendings, &c

Comment: Actually it sounds like you want to do a correlated subquery.. which gets a little more complicated.. read about syntax here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: Better than to my answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT customers.id,customers.firstname,customers.lastname,customers.email,orders.time,orders.notes,pendings.date_updated,pendings.issue,appointments.closed,appointments.job_description,backup_plans.expiration FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN orders
ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
RIGHT JOIN pendings
ON customers.id = pendings.customer_id
RIGHT JOIN appointments
ON customers.id = appointments.customer_id
RIGHT JOIN backup_plans
ON customers.id = backup_plans.customer_id
ORDER BY orders.time DESC, pendings.date_updated DESC,  appointments.closed DESC,  backup_plans.expiration DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Close, but what I need it to do is select **every** customer, and `LIMIT` the orders, pendings, &c

Comment: If one user have multiple order than? @tyler-shuster

Comment: @tyler-shuster I dont think mysql support this.. but I find some thing with UNION

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through subqueries or with additional `JOIN`s. Here's an example of each. (NOTE: I use SQL Server, so it's possible that some of the syntax that I'm used to isn't supported in the same way in MySQL). I'm only doing these example with the Orders, but hopefully you can extend the ideas to the other tables.

Using subqueries:

```
SELECT
    C.id,
    SQ_O.time,
    SQ_O.notes
FROM
    Customers C
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        C2.Customer_ID,
        O.time,
        O.notes
    FROM
        Customers C2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O ON O.customer_id = C2.id
    ORDER BY
        O.time DESC LIMIT 1
) SQ_O ON SQ_O.customer_id = C.id
```

Using multiple `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT
    C.id,
    O1.time,
    O1.notes
FROM
    Customers C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O1 ON O1.customer_id = C.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders O2 ON O2.customer_id = C.id AND O2.time > O1.time
WHERE
    O2.customer_id IS NULL -- Basically we're excluding any rows where another order was found with a later time than O1
```

If exact matches in Orders.time are possible than you'll need additional criteria on which one to choose.

Comment: Thanks! That looks really close to what I'd like to do but I'm having some trouble based on dialect. I updated the original question.

Comment: It looks like in your subquery you have "customers.id", but then you refer to it outside of the subquery as "customer_id".

Comment: I changed that, but now the times and notes fields are empty.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can rely on no customer having their two most recent `orders` having the same `time`, this should work:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email, o.*
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id, MAX(`time`) AS maxTime
   FROM orders
   GROUP BY customer_id 
) AS lastO ON c.id = lastO.customer_id
LEFT JOIN orders AS o 
   ON lastO.customer_id = o.customer_id
   AND lastO.maxTime = o.`time`
;
```

As long as the other tables can also be relied upon to have only one `MAX` value per customer, you should be able to append similar `JOIN`s for them. The issue with multiple of the same "last" `time\date_updated\closed\etc..` for a customer is that they will multiply results. For example, pairs of the same `time` in `orders` and pairs of `date_updated` in `pending` on the same customer will result in 4 rows instead of two as every "last" row for that customer in `orders` is paired up with every "last" row in `pending`.